# Windows File upload does not close after successfull upload using Protractor

Tags: javascript, file-upload, protractor

I'm using below method to upload a file in Windows File dialog box in Protractor.
I'm able to successfully upload the file,but the dialog box is not closing.

Just element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath) works fine for upload.

The other commented code I have tried,but it did not close.Looks broswer actions are not triggering any action on it.

```
   function uploadFile(absolutePath) {
    return element(by.css('input[type="file"]')).sendKeys(absolutePath).then(() => {
    // return element(by.id('uploadButton')).click();
    //  browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ESC).perform();       
    //  browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.ENTER).perform();
});
}
```